# How do i append coordinates to a csv containing State names in python in less time

Tags: python, pandas, api, data-science

I have a working code which does the job using opencage API but takes significantly longer time. How can i implement the same in less time.
The df contains a list of all cities of the world
this code sections iterates through all the city names and appends their coordintes

link to my [code and csv file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H5k9rw0rJdb5lSf3RIxefatY346AX951?usp=sharing)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiCd3.png)

```
key = 'KEY'  # get Your api key from:  https://opencagedata.com
geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)

list_lat = []   
list_long = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    State = row['city_ascii']       
    query = str(State)

    results = geocoder.geocode(query)   
    lat = results[0]['geometry']['lat']
    long = results[0]['geometry']['lng']

    list_lat.append(lat)
    list_long.append(long)

df['lat'] = list_lat   
df['lon'] = list_long

df.head()
```

Comment: @Chris did the needful and aslo added link to my code,csv file and screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `geopy` and pandas's apply:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="so_test_YoDa")

cities = pd.read_csv('cities.csv', header = 0)

def getLatLong(city):
    location = geolocator.geocode(city)

    return location.latitude, location.longitude

cities[["lat", "lon"]] = cities.city.apply(getLatLong).apply(pd.Series)

print(cities)
```

**Output:**

```
          city        lat         lon
0        Tokyo  35.682839  139.759455
1     New York  40.712728  -74.006015
2  Mexico City  19.432630  -99.133178
3       Mumbai  18.938771   72.835335
4    Sao Paulo -23.550651  -46.633382
```

**Sample Data (CSV):**

```
city
Tokyo
New York
Mexico City
Mumbai
Sao Paulo
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code is slow because of the network latency when hitting the `OpenCageGeocode` multiple times. Concurrency can help with I/O operations (in your case fetching coords from remote API).

What I did is placing the code that fetch the coords in a function then, executed this function with all possible states in a thread pool of 5 workers:

```
import concurrent.futures

key = 'API KEY'  # get Your api key from:  https://opencagedata.com
geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)

list_lat = []   
list_long = []


def load_coords(row):       
    query = str(row['city_ascii'])

    results = geocoder.geocode(query)
    lat = results[0]['geometry']['lat1']
    long = results[0]['geometry']['lng1']

    return (lat, long)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    results = executor.map(load_coords, (row for _, row in df.iterrows()))
    for coords in results:
        list_lat.append(coords[0])
        list_long.append(coords[1])
```

Number of workers determine who many requests are being done at the same time, so your code approximately will be five times faster.

**Note**: This code may not be working because I do not have the API' Key to test it, also I removed error handling for simplicity.

**Update:** code edited.